# run_later with rackup fails to exit with ctrl-c - Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety, sinatra, rackup

I'm running a Sinatra application with rackup using this run_later https://github.com/elecklider/sinatra_run_later module (my own fork of https://github.com/pmamediagroup/sinatra_run_later). I can't, however, seem to get it to exit cleanly when I send ctrl-c to rackup. It kicks back with the error `ERROR SystemExit: exit` on line 38. How can I get it to exit nicely when I close the rackup process?

**EDIT:**

I've been screwing around with this and the error is raised here:

```
trap :INT do
  RunLater::Worker.shutdown
  exit # here.
end
```

And it seems that commenting out the whole `trap` block gets it to clean up nicely. In essence, this answers the question of how to get it to clean up nicely but I have no idea why so if anyone can offer some clarification I'd really appreciate it.